# SQL Server 2012: sum over order by gives error Incorrect syntax near 'order'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

```
declare @t table (cid int, amount int, cname varchar)

insert into @t 
values (6, 20, 'C'), (7, 30, 'C'), (8, 10, 'C'), (9, 10, 'D')

select 
    sum(amount) over (partition by cname order by cid),
    *
from @t
```

Throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx

Isn't sum over order by supported in SQL Server 2012? If I remove order by and use only partition by it works but for 'C' I get 60 for all rows. I want to get running total.

More info:

- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    11.0.2100.60
- Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools 11.0.2100.60
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514

Database option -> compatibility level only shows 2000, 2005 and 2008, with 2008 selected.

Trying to run

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name 
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110
```

Throws an error:

> Valid values of the database compatibility level are 80, 90, or 100.

Comment: Hmmm, are you using SSMS 2012 with an earlier version of the database engine?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah I guess, you're right. `select @@version` gave me `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
 Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
`. Not sure how that's even possible.

Comment: SSMS is an interface; it can talk to multiple versions of the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, that's true, what I meant was how did they (IT admin) manage to install SSMS 2012 with 2008 engine? If you run the 2012 installer, it will install 2012 SSMS and 2012 engine, yeah? Did they install 2008 engine and 2012 SSMS on top of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cumulative sums are not supported until SQL Server 2012+.  Presumably, you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008 or your compatibility setting is set to 105 or less (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)).

In these versions, you can use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, s.amount
from @t t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.amount) as amount
      from @t t2
      where t2.cname = t.cname and t2.cid <= t.cid
     ) s;
```

Comment: @sgeddes . . . I clarified more the point about compatibility levels.

Comment: @sgeddes : With the default 2012 settings, OP's query should work.

Comment: Thanks, just saw that.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It's an SQL 2012 install but when I look at the database options -> compatibility level, I only have 2000 (80), 2005 (90) and 2008(100), with 2008 selected. Any ideas why 2012 wouldn't be in that list on a 2012?

Comment: @DarkKnight I edited the question with more details, if that helps.