# Getting distinct rows for overlapping timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, where-clause

I have the following result set which I get from SQL Server:

```
employeeNumber | start_date | start_time | end_date     | end_time
---------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------
123            | 10-03-2020 |  18:13:55  |  10-03-2020  | 22:59:46
123            | 10-03-2020 |  18:24:22  |  10-03-2020  | 22:59:51
123            | 10-03-2020 |  23:24:22  |  10-03-2020  | 23:59:51
123            | 11-03-2020 |  18:25:25  |  11-03-2020  | 20:59:51
123            | 12-03-2020 |  18:40:22  |  12-03-2020  | 22:59:52
```

For some cases I have multiple rows for the same overlapping time (row 1 and 2) as above but with a different start and end time (difference in seconds or minutes).

While my query is a simple select query that fetches the data from the source table, What can i add in the where clause to fetch distinct rows for such overlapping timestamp rows. i.e. for the above query i would want the result set to return the following :

```
employeeNumber | start_date | start_time | end_date     | end_time    
---------------+------------+------------+--------------+----------
123            | 10-03-2020 |  18:13:55  |  10-03-2020  | 22:59:46
123            | 10-03-2020 |  23:24:22  |  10-03-2020  | 23:59:51
123            | 11-03-2020 |  18:25:25  |  11-03-2020  | 20:59:51
123            | 12-03-2020 |  18:40:22  |  12-03-2020  | 22:59:52
```

Below is my query :

```
select 
    employeeNumber, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time
from 
    emp_data
where 
    employeeNumber = 123
order by 
    employeeNumber;
```

I can probably do with fetching only the first record but what would the where clause be.

Any help is appreciated as I am not very familiar with SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you split the date/times into two columns?  That just makes any code more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated.  You need to keep track of "starts" and "ends".  I am going to assume that your columns are `datetime`s or something similar that can be combined into a single column:

```
with e as (
      select e.employeeNumber, v.dt, sum(v.inc) as inc,
             sum(sum(v.inc)) over (partition by e.employeeNumber order by v.dt) as in_outs
      from emp_data e cross apply
           (values (start_date + start_time, 1),
                   (end_date + end_time, -1)
           ) v(dt, inc)
      group by e.employeeNumber, v.dt
     )
select employeeNumber, min(dt) as start_datetime, max(dt) as end_datetime
from (select e.*,
             sum(case when in_outs = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employeeNumber order by dt) as grp
      from e
     ) e
where in_outs <> 0
group by employeeNumber, grp;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e5ba87a4ea72d6e43671c30bf8444e5b) is a db<>fiddle.

What is this doing?

- First the date/times are converted to date times.
- Then the columns are unpivoted and identified as starts and ends, along with +1 or -1 to indicate whether the employee is "entering" or "existing" at that time.
- These are accumulated.
- Now you have a gaps and islands problem, where you want to find continue periods of "in"s.  The "islands" are identified using a cumulative sum of "ins".
- Then these are aggregated.

EDIT:

You can replace the cumulative sum with:

```
from (select e.*,
             (select sum(case when e2.in_outs = 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
              from e e2
              where e2.employeeNumber = e.employeeNumber
                    e2.dt <= e.dt
             ) as grp
      from e
     ) e
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This SQL is near to perfect, With one issue where in the query is throwing `Syntax error for order by.`. After some R&D and with the help of an another post of yours [SQL Server 2012: sum over order by gives error Incorrect syntax near 'order'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38065881/sql-server-2012-sum-over-order-by-gives-error-incorrect-syntax-near-order), I was able to conclude that `order by` does not work with `sum` in SQL server with compatibility less than 105 and mine is set to 100, which unfortunately can not be changed. Can you please with same.

Comment: You have suggested to make use of `outer apply`. Can you please help with how this can be incorporated in the query that you suggested.

Comment: The outer apply worked and is fine now. However, For records that are not overlapping such as
`123            | 10-03-2020 |  23:24:22  |  10-03-2020  | 23:59:51`

It gives the result as :
`123            | 10-03-2020 |  23:24:22  |  10-03-2020  | 23:24:51`

where in the start date and end date column values are same which is the _start date_.
Thus can you please help me with any suggestion on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Also, if there are multiple rows, among which no 2 rows overlap, then in that case it gives the result as the same start time in both the start and end column for each respective row.

Comment: @Allan . . . Can you ask a new question with the sample data you have in mind?  Setting up a db fiddle is also helpful.

Comment: Have asked a new question having all the information of what i have done till now and also along with a db fiddle. [Link to the Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869021/getting-distinct-rows-for-overlapping-timestamp-sql-server). Thanks.

Comment: Hi Gordon, did you get a chance to look at the query? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869021/getting-distinct-rows-for-overlapping-timestamp-sql-server) Thanks.